# Copy Folder on WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, copy, winrt-async

For now, I just know how to copy file using:

```
IStorageFolder dir = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

IStorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///file.txt"));

await file.CopyAsync(dir, "file.txt");
```

When I try to copy folder and all the content inside, I cannot find the API like `CopyAsync` above.

**Is it possible to copy folder and all the content in WinRT?**

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I can't find the API for copy folder like the copy file above.

Comment: Do you get a compiler-error or linker-error?

Comment: No error, The problem is, I don't know if the API for copy folder is exist or not. So, I try to asking here if I miss something. If the API really didn't exist, than I must do manually, looping for all the sub folder and copy one by one all the files.

Comment: Gotcha... As far as I know, WinRT is limiting its capabilities in working with files/folders (sandbox)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code above didn't satisfy me (too specific), i made my own generic one so figured i could share it :

```
public static async Task CopyFolderAsync(StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destinationContainer, string desiredName = null)
    {
        StorageFolder destinationFolder = null;
            destinationFolder = await destinationContainer.CreateFolderAsync(
                desiredName ?? source.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }
        foreach (var folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync())
        {
            await CopyFolderAsync(folder, destinationFolder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When creating folder, does replace existing remove the old folder (along with it's content) or using that existing folder as destination?

Comment: I'd say the existing folder is replaced by the created empty one, so the existing content is lost. But i haven't tested to be honest.

Comment: This works great. In addition, I have added 2 DeleteAsync() statements to remove all files and folders. I wanted to move the folder from one path to another.

Comment: Very compact. To wrap up here is the calling code to copy from Appx to localFolder `Dim localFldr = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("LocalFolder")
        If localFldr Is Nothing Then
            Dim appFldr = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("LocalFolder")
            Await CopyFolderAsync(appFldr, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder)
        End If`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use

```
StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync();
```

from `Windows.Storage`-namespace.

The result of the call is a

```
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem>
```

containing all of the files and folders of the current folder.
You can then work on those.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227286.aspx) for a further reference.

Comment: Thank you for your information, but after I check again, the result from `StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync()` is `IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem>`. For now, I try to implement it using recursive, I'll update the code when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Base on [bash.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248287/copy-folder-on-winrt/18248677#18248677) answer, I generate my own Copy Folder:

```
namespace Directories
{
    private string ROOT = "root";

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            CopyFolder(ROOT);
        }

        private async void CopyFolder(string path)
        {
            IStorageFolder destination = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            IStorageFolder root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

            if (path.Equals(ROOT) && !await FolderExistAsync(ROOT))
                await destination.CreateFolderAsync(ROOT);

            destination = await destination.GetFolderAsync(path);
            root = await root.GetFolderAsync(path);

            IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> items = await root.GetItemsAsync();
            foreach (IStorageItem item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
                {
                    IStorageFile presFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                        new Uri("ms-appx:///" + path.Replace("\\", "/") + "/" + item.Name));

                    // Do copy file to destination folder
                    await presFile.CopyAsync(destination);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If folder doesn't exist, than create new one on destination folder
                    if (!await FolderExistAsync(path + "\\" + item.Name))
                        await destination.CreateFolderAsync(item.Name);

                    // Do recursive copy for every items inside
                    CopyFolder(path + "\\" + item.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> FolderExistAsync(string foldername)
        {
            IStorageFolder destination = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            try
            {
                await destination.GetFolderAsync(foldername);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example using `root` as the root folder:

```
- root
  - sub1
    - sub1-1.txt
    - sub1-2.txt
    - sub1-3.txt
    - sub1-4.txt
  - sub2
    - sub2-1.txt
    - sub2-2.txt
    - sub2-3.txt
    - sub2-4.txt
  - root1.txt
  - root2.txt
  - root3.txt
  - root4.txt
```

It will copy from `InstalledLocation` folder to `LocalFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if C# supports the Array.map method, but this is what the copyFolderAsync code would look like for JavaScript

```
CreationCollisionOption = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption;
NameCollisionOption = Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption;

copyFolderAsync = function(sourceFolder, destFolder) {
  return destFolder.createFolderAsync(sourceFolder.name, CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists).then(function(destSubFolder) {
    return sourceFolder.getFilesAsync().then(function(files) {
      return WinJS.Promise.join(files.map(function(file) {
        return file.copyAsync(destSubFolder, file.name, NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting);
      }));
    }).then(function() {
      return sourceFolder.getFoldersAsync();
    }).then(function(folders) {
      return WinJS.Promise.join(folders.map(function(folder) {
        return copyFolderAsync(folder, destSubFolder);
      }));
    });
  });
};
```